# yandex-tank: "Waiting for aggregator to finish" forever

Tags: yandex-tank

I did web search for "site:stackoverflow.com yandex-tank Waiting for aggregator to finish" and found nothing that specific.

I start JMeter via Yandex-Tank (YT) and after JMeter finishes YT continues to write in log "Waiting for aggregator to finish" like forever. I've found some discussion here: https://gitter.im/yandex/yandex-tank?at=5ce2c4e36366992a94ef7826:

> Покопал ещё, оказывается эти строки там были, но их убрали в коммите:
>   47623dd4b7a08e5383cbb4144eecc13edbdf3e96 Видимо закрытие reader нужно
>   перенести по аналогии с Bfg в plugins/JMeter/plugin.py В функции
>   end_test и is_test_finished

it is a discussion board in Russian, brief translation for non-russian speakers: "closing of reader should be moved to end_test & is_test_finished like it's done for BFG plugin".

However, as I see in code `end_test` and `is_test_finished` `reader.close()` is already there `yandextank/plugins/JMeter/plugin.py`:

```
def is_test_finished(self):
    retcode = self.process.poll()
    aggregator = self.core.job.aggregator
    if not aggregator.reader.jmeter_finished and retcode is not None:
        logger.info(
            "JMeter process finished with exit code: %s, waiting for aggregator",
            retcode)
        self.retries = 0
        aggregator.reader.jmeter_finished = True
        return -1
    elif aggregator.reader.jmeter_finished is True:
        print("aggregator.reader.jmeter_finished is True")
        if aggregator.reader.agg_finished:
            self.reader.close()
            return retcode
        else:
            logger.info("Waiting for aggregator to finish")
            return -1
    else:
        return -1

def end_test(self, retcode):
    if self.process:
        gracefully_shutdown = self.__graceful_shutdown()
        if not gracefully_shutdown:
            self.__kill_jmeter()
    if self.process_stderr:
        self.process_stderr.close()
    self.core.add_artifact_file(self.jmeter_log)
    self.reader.close()
    return retcode
```

How to fix that (to make YT finish cleanly after JM finish)?